# Is it possible to disable "lazy unloading" of forms?

Tags: orbeon

Lets say we have 2+ people.

1. Each of them is clicking link which will show them form rendered by Orbeon Forms. They all sent http request in same second.
2. Orbeon Forms received all requests and read into memory xforms form from hard drive, rendered it and sent it in response to all clients.
3. All client received same copy of rendered form.

Is it possible to configure Orbeon Forms in a way that it will reread and rerender xforms form for every request it will receive?

I don't care about efficiency, this server has very small traffic.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption in point 3, *all clients received same copy of rendered form*, isn't accurate. Even if the request comes at exactly the same time, for exactly the same form, Orbeon Forms assigns a different UUID to each request. You can find this UUID in the value of a hidden field in the HTML sent to the browser. And that UUID is then sent by the browser with every Ajax request sent to the server for that specific page.

Regarding your question on whether Orbeon Forms could re-read the XForms for every request: yes, this is possible, and often is what is happening, but for performance reasons Orbeon Forms has a cache to avoid some expensive initial processing of the XForms at every request. You can think of this as a way to avoid "recompiling the form" at every request if the form hasn't changed.